# WTForms Label Position / Hiding Label

Tags: css, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've build a form using HTML / CSS with Bootstrap and I'm trying to integrate WTForms into it - everything was working fine and formatting perfectly until I started formatting the fields using wtf.form_field function and now I seem to have excess labels.

Can anyone tell me how to a) reposition the labels or b) do not render them at all?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="label-name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Desired Label Position</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
 {{ wtf.form_field(form.crm_description, class="form-control", placeholder="Placeholder Text", rows="1", readonly=true)}}

         </div>
     </div>
```

And here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Example of field positions]
The label on the left side is by design, however wtforms seems to want to add it's own label on the top of the field itself that I can't seem to move.

thanks

Comment: Looks like you are using Flask-Bootstrap library to render your forms? Have a look at the [macro definition for `form_field`](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html#L29), there doesn't appear to be a way to specify for it not to render a label, but there is a `fom-type` parameter which you can ask for a 'horizontal' form type which sounds like it should do what you want, eg. include `form-type="horizontal"` to your `wtf.form_field()` function call.

Answer (score -1):

look at the the class and set the css label display to none

for example:

```html
<style>
    label{
      display: None;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't look like it has any side effects...

Comment: you may need to check the label class , use inspect on chrome to view the style block for this.